# PostgreSQL fails on empty constructor arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, database, postgresql, casting

I have encountered a strange situation with arrays, which looks like a bug in PostgreSQL, unless I'm missing something...

According to PostgreSQL documentation, constructor and string presentations of arrays are interchangeable, i.e. we can either write `ARRAY[1,2,3]` or `'{1,2,3}'`, which is the same.

However, I have found one case when they are not treated the same.

I am using an automatic SQL generator for multi-row updates that spits out the following:

```sql
UPDATE "myTable" AS t SET "data"=v."data"::int[] FROM (VALUES(1, array[]))
AS v("id", "data") WHERE t.id=v.id
```

The table is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  data int[] NULL
);
```

Executing that query produces error - `cannot determine type of empty array`, even though we are clearly casting the column type.

And if I replace `array[]` with the equivalent `'{}'`, then it suddenly works.

I've never seen this happen before, this is first time, perhaps a unique situation, but from what I see, it goes against PostgreSQL documentation for interchangeable array presentation.

---

More examples, to explain the issue:

**These work:**

```sql
UPDATE "myTable" AS t SET "data"=v."data"::int[] FROM (VALUES(1, array[1,2,3]))
AS v("id", "data") WHERE t.id=v.id
```

```sql
UPDATE "myTable" AS t SET "data"=v."data"::int[] FROM (VALUES(1, '{1,2,3}'))
AS v("id", "data") WHERE t.id=v.id
```

```sql
UPDATE "myTable" AS t SET "data"=v."data"::int[] FROM (VALUES(1, '{}'))
AS v("id", "data") WHERE t.id=v.id
```

**This one doesn't work:**

```sql
UPDATE "myTable" AS t SET "data"=v."data"::int[] FROM (VALUES(1, array[]))
AS v("id", "data") WHERE t.id=v.id
```

So the type casting for array constructor works, for as long as the array isn't empty, just as it is empty, then the type casting stops working.

Comment: There is little bit different processing when you use the keyword `ARRAY`. In this case, you have to append type info - `select array[]::integer[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is supported with type info:

```
pokus1=# select array[];
ERROR:  cannot determine type of empty array
LINE 1: select array[];
               ^
HINT:  Explicitly cast to the desired type, for example ARRAY[]::integer[].
pokus1=# select array[]::integer[];
  array
 -------
  {}
 (1 row)
```

Comment: But the thing is, we are casting the type already, and it works for non-empty array, it is only for empty arrays it suddenly refuses to cast constructor presentation....

Comment: @vitaly-t: It works for non-empty arrays because the type of the elements define the type of the array. In an empty array there are no elements that could define the type. Similar to: `select null` what data type is that? But I agree that it should at least be consistent between the two notations (i.e. I would expect the string literal to also require an explicit cast)

Comment: So, PostgreSQL just ignores the casing we use upfront - `"data"=v."data"::int[]`? That means for every value in my UPDATE I have to specify in-line casting?

Comment: @vitaly-t - Postgres doesn't ignore it - just doesn't propagate this information to `VALUE` clause. There are two different code paths - one is based on type input - when you use a string, second is a ARRAY constructor - and it has not info about expected type.

Comment: @PavelStehule interesting, then why does it support that casting syntax in the first place...it accepts the syntax, just doesn't use it... :)

Comment: @vitaly-t: the parser is able to detect numeric values.  - Probably enhancing of this behave is in PostgreSQL ToDo - but it was not too important for anybody to fix it.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your answer I was able to fix the issue in my library - `pg-promise`: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/272